# Sklearn SVM - how to get a list of the wrong predictions?

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, svm

I am not an expert user. I know that I can obtain the confusion matrix, but I would like to obtain a list of the rows that have been classified in a wrong way in order to study them after classification.

On stackoverflow I found this [Can I get a list of wrong predictions in SVM score function in scikit-learn](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45176469/can-i-get-a-list-of-wrong-predictions-in-svm-score-function-in-scikit-learn) but I am not sure to have understood everything.

This is an example code.

```python
# importing necessary libraries
from sklearn import datasets
from sklearn.metrics import confusion_matrix
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split

# loading the iris dataset
iris = datasets.load_iris()

# X -> features, y -> label
X = iris.data
y = iris.target

# dividing X, y into train and test data
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, random_state = 0)

# training a linear SVM classifier
from sklearn.svm import SVC
svm_model_linear = SVC(kernel = 'linear', C = 1).fit(X_train, y_train)
svm_predictions = svm_model_linear.predict(X_test)

# model accuracy for X_test  
accuracy = svm_model_linear.score(X_test, y_test)

# creating a confusion matrix
cm = confusion_matrix(y_test, svm_predictions)
```

To iterate through the rows and to find the wrong ones, the proposed solution is:

```python
predictions = clf.predict(inputs)
for input, prediction, label in zip(inputs, predictions, labels):
  if prediction != label:
    print(input, 'has been classified as ', prediction, 'and should be ', label)
```

I didn't understand what is "input"/"inputs". If I adapt this code to my code, like this:

```python
for input, prediction, label in zip (X_test, svm_predictions, y_test):
  if prediction != label:
    print(input, 'has been classified as ', prediction, 'and should be ', label)
```

I obtain:

```python
[6.  2.7 5.1 1.6] has been classified as  2 and should be  1
```

Is the row 6 the wrong row? What are the numbers after the 6.? I am asking this because I am using the same code on a dataset that is bigger than this one, so I would like to be sure that I am doing the right things. 
I am not posting the other dataset because unfortunately I can't, but the problem there is that I obtained something like this:

```python
  (0, 253)  0.5339655767137572
  (0, 601)  0.27665553856928027
  (0, 1107) 0.7989633757962163 has been classified as  7 and should be  3
  (0, 885)  0.3034934766501018
  (0, 1295) 0.6432561790864061
  (0, 1871) 0.7029318585026516 has been classified as  7 and should be  6
  (0, 1020) 1.0 has been classified as  3 and should be  8
```

When I count every line of this last output, I obtain the double of the lines of the test set... So I am not sure that I am analyzing exactly the wrong list of predicted results…

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is the row 6 the wrong row? What are the numbers after the 6.?

No - `[6.  2.7 5.1 1.6]` is the actual sample (i.e. its features). To get the index of the wrong row, we should modify slightly the `for` loop:

```python
for idx, input, prediction, label in zip(enumerate(X_test), X_test, svm_predictions, y_test):
    if prediction != label:
        print("No.", idx[0], 'input,',input, ', has been classified as', prediction, 'and should be', label)
```

The result now being

```python
No. 37 input, [ 6.   2.7  5.1  1.6] , has been classified as 2 and should be 1
```

Which means that `X_test[37]`, which is `[ 6.   2.7  5.1  1.6]`, has been predicted by our SVM as 2, while its true label is 1.

Let's confirm this reading:

```python
X_test[37]
# array([ 6. ,  2.7,  5.1,  1.6])

svm_predictions[37]
# 2

y_test[37]
# 1
```

This result is in agreement with your confusion matrix `cm`, which shows indeed only one mis-classified sample in `X_test`:

```python
cm
# result:
array([[13,  0,  0],
       [ 0, 15,  1],
       [ 0,  0,  9]], dtype=int64)
```

A more elegant `for` loop, since the enumeration includes the samples themselves, could be:

```python
for idx, prediction, label in zip(enumerate(X_test), svm_predictions, y_test):
    if prediction != label:
        print("Sample", idx, ', has been classified as', prediction, 'and should be', label)
```

which gives

```python
Sample (37, array([ 6. ,  2.7,  5.1,  1.6])) , has been classified as 2 and should be 1
```

Answer (score 3):

If you want to just get a list of the incorrectly classified instances, you can do the following:

```
# with the following sentence you can get a mask of the items bad classified
mask = np.logical_not(np.equal(y_test, predictions))
# Now you can use the mask to see the elements bad classified:
print(f"Elements wrong classified: {X_test[mask]}")
print(f"Prediction by the model for each of those elements: {predictions[mask]}")
print(f"Actual value for each of those elements: {np.asarray(y_test)[mask]}")
```